# removing comma and -

Tags: bash, awk, sed

How can I clean in bash the following line

```
-,2,8,--,-,2,6,--,-,-1,2,--,-,0,4,--,-,1,5,--,-,-5,2
```

in order to get

```
 2,8,2,6,-1,2,0,4,1,5,-5,2
```

I only want positive and negative numbers separated by comma

Comment: @anubhava Yes, for example, sed -e 's/--//g' | sed -e '/-,//g'

Comment: `sed 's/^-*,//;:a;s/,[-]*,/,/;t a'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {j=0; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/^-?[0-9]/) printf "%s%s", (++j>1?OFS:""), $i; print ""}' file 
2,8,2,6,-1,2,0,4,1,5,-5,2
```

Loop through each field, testing if the current field is a number optionally preceded with `-`. If it is then print the field preceded by nothing if it's the first matching field on the line or by the output field separator otherwise. When done printing the fields print a newline.

Comment: sure, explanation added.

Answer (score 2):

You can run it through this `sed` script:

```
sed -e 's/--*,//g' -e 's/,--*$//'
```

That wipes out every substring consisting of one or more minus signs (`-`) followed by a comma (`,`), and, separately, any trailing substring consisting of a comma followed by one or more minus signs.

Comment: @peak, I accept your edit, but it would have been more appropriate (and more informative to future readers) to comment instead of editing.

Comment: @JohnBollinger - Thanks for accepting the edit, which I made because there's not much interest in what is effectively a typo. Also I wanted to upvote the answer :-)   Please note that not only is the fact there was an edit plainly shown, but also anyone interested in the history can easily enough click on the "edited" hyperlink.

Answer (score 1):

A gnu-awk solution:

```
str='-,2,8,--,-,2,6,--,-,-1,2,--,-,0,4,--,-,1,5,--,-,-5,2'
awk -v FPAT='-?[0-9]+' '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s%s", $i, (i<NF)?",":RS}' <<< "$str"
2,8,2,6,-1,2,0,4,1,5,-5,2
```

A non-gnu awk solution:

```
str=$(awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS=","} /^-?[[:digit:]]+/{print $1}' <<< "$str")
```

Output:

```
echo "${str%,}"
2,8,2,6,-1,2,0,4,1,5,-5,2
```

Comment: thank you for the code...what does BEGIN{RS=ORS=","} ? and /^-?[[:digit:]]+ it means that gets the  number with or without -?

Comment: Yes ` /^-?[[:digit:]]+` match 1 or more digits with optional `-` at the start. ` BEGIN{RS=ORS=","}` sets input and output record separators as comma

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
egrep -o "\-?[0-9]+" | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/,/g'
```

or:

```
egrep -o "\-?[0-9]+" | xargs | sed 's/ /,/g'
```